# Как корректно выводить таблицу в телеграм?

Tags: python, telebot

Мне нужно, чтобы мой бот по запросу выводил данные в виде таблицы в тг. Пробовал с помощью библиотеки tabulate, но вот незадача: она выводит кривые таблицы, а-ля:

```
|| name     ||   game ||   win ||   lose || winrate   ||
| Brakinon |     12 |     8 |      4 | 66.67%    |
```

```
======  ======  =====  ======  =========
name      game    win    lose  winrate
======  ======  =====  ======  =========
Chenkoid       26     14      12  53.85%
======  ======  =====  ======  =========
```

```
name        game    win    lose  winrate
--------  ------  -----  ------  ---------
Brakinon   12     8      4  66.67%
```

Может быть кто то знает, как можно выводить в тг ровные таблицы?

Comment: Ровно вряд ли получится, телеграмм адаптирует информацию под монитор клиента. Поэтому лучше отправлять картинкой. Для этого можете воспользоваться библиотекой `Pillow`

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй использовать невидимый символ "⠀" вместо пробела, а составитель таблиц написать самому не трудно впринципе

Comment: вероятно, стоит уточнить, что это за «невидимый символ», и как его получить.

Comment: между ковычек невидимый символ, просто скопируй пустоту между ковычками